# How to alter node body content through Views pre render hook?

Tags: views

I have build the view to display node title and node body also I have applied combined fields filter which searches the keyword in title and body and returns the results.

While rendering the contents I have to render the title and body with the highlighted keywords that  are been searched.

Currently I am using hook_views_pre_render to alter the same.But unable to replace the body text with my generated results.

How can I alter the body contents?

Answer (score 0):

What variable are you modifying? When I modify Views results I usually use [`hook_views_post_execute`](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_post_execute/7). I then modify the appropriate element in `$view->result`. You may be able to do the same from `hook_views_pre_render` (I don't use that one often especially in this type of case).